# Primefaces fileupload : upload button enabled even when there's an error message

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

We're using Primefaces 5.0; when we click on the choose / browse button, 'upload' is enabled even if there's a file size limit or file type error. The user can then click the upload button and submit a file they should not be able to. I can produce this issue with the sample code from the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml) :

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
           update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
</h:form>
```

I was not able to find anyone else reporting this issue; any ideas? Upgrading to a more recent version of Primefaces is not currently an option.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can ALWAYS create a TEST project and see if it is fixed in a newer release

Comment: If the problem is with the current version I'm using (doubtful, since I can't find any reports of it), I need a workaround. Downvoting my question and telling me to look at a newer version, when I've already said upgrading is not an option, is in no way helpful. Neither are CAPS.

Comment: Absence of issue reports does not mean absence of (fixed) issues. If you **try** with a newer version and it works there, you can use that information to maybe create a workaround (overriding a PF java class, maybe some javascript). But if that is not an option, then unfortunately I'm not able to help you any further, sorry. I don't have time to start debugging this and find an actual cause (something you could have tried to) let alone to write a workaround. I hope I gave you some pointers now to start investigating while you wait for others to help. (removed downvote)

Comment: I **tried** to remove my downvote, but it is locked unless the question is answered. Sorry